# Cual es este formato?

Tags: php, array, json, serialización

tengo que transformar este string a un array de PHP pero no logro de reconocerlo, no se a que lenguaje pertenece o como se llama

```json
a:2:{ 
 s:11:"merchant_id";
 s:44:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
 s:8:"terminal";s:3:"123";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una cadena [serializada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php), la utilidad es poder transportar información en formato array entre distintos sistemas, o bien poder almacenarse en una base de datos (por ejemplo). Usa [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php) para convertirla nuevamente a array

```php
> $str = 'a:2:{s:11:"merchant_id";s:44:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";s:8:"terminal";s:3:"123";}';
> var_export(unserialize($str));
array (
  'merchant_id' => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  'terminal' => '123',
)
```